# What do you mean by "ordinary preposition"?

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases, infinitive-vs-gerund, bare-infinitives

I can't specifically figure out the meaning of ordinary preposition, especially with "to".

When does verb + ing come after to?

And when to + bare infinitive?

Comment: _To_ serves two functions in English. It is a preposition, and it also serves as a particle which marks an infinitive. Your English dictionary will tell you what _ordinary_ means. The word has no special meaning in grammar. When you see a phrase like _to eat,_ that is the infinitive of the verb _eat._ The word marks the infinitive: it identifies the infinitive and is part of it. Every other use of the word _to_ is as a preposition. In _to the lighthouse, let's go to the beach, I am addicted to watching TV,_ etc., the word to is a plain, ordinary preposition.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, ***to*** can be either a preposition or an infinitive marker. Now if you want to learn how they are used in sentences you should learn the words more deeply. In fact, you should learn whether or not a verb or adjective is followed by a certain preposition or not.

Some verbs can be followed by ***to*** where ***to*** is a preposition:

> - She admitted to being strict with her children.
> - He confessed to stealing the jewelry.

***to*** may be a part of a verb-group in two-word or three-word verbs:

> - The remark about an election inevitably gave rise to widespread speculation.

On the other hand, you have verbs or adjectives that can be followed by to+infinitive. Here ***to*** acts as infinitive marker.

> - He refused to accept our offer.

---

Extra Info:

Please note that there are certain sentences in which ***to*** acts as an adverb; I don't know much of them, but one is as below.

- push the door to.